# Why does adding a month to a Date object return a strange number?

Tags: javascript

The following returns 11 which is correct.

```
var month = d.getMonth();
alert(month);
```

When I try adding a month to it returns something very different

```
var month = d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
alert(month);
```

It returns: 1513230546878

Comment: This is `timestamp`. If you want month then simply do `d.getMonth()` again.

Comment: Just use `var month = d.getMonth()+1;`.  (although you'll end up with 12, when presumably the range of months is from 0-11).

Comment: If you have any doubts regarding return type of functions in any programming language just go through the documentation. In your case its clearly given that the return type is 'number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC '. Have the practice of googling and reading docs before asking general questions.

Comment: You're right! I added a 1 and it returned a 0 which I assume is a zero based January representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return values of methods that you are using in your code are as follows

1. `d.getMonth()` - A Number, from 0 to 11, representing the month ([Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp))
2. `d.setMonth()` - A Number, representing the number of milliseconds between the date object and midnight January 1 1970 ([Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setmonth.asp))

Please note, `d.setMonth()` will modify your `Date` object in place. So, if you want your code to work as expected, you can write as follows

```js
var d = new Date()
var month = d.getMonth();
alert(month);

d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
alert(d.getMonth());
```

Answer (score 0):

`d.setMonth()` method returns the updated timestamp value (See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth)). That's why you got a long number.

If you want to get the month you will use as per below

```
var d = new Date("2017-10-03");
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
var month = d.getMonth(); // get new month
alert(month);
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In java script, if you write this:

```
var month = d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
```

**You get a timestamp**. Meaning, an integer number representing the month you chose.

This is because, setDate accepts a dayValue parameter:

```
Date.setDate(dayValue)
```

Meaning that:

```
  var dt = new Date("Aug 28, 2008 23:30:00");
    dt.setDate(24);
    console.log(dt);
```

will result in:

```
Sun Aug 24 2008 23:30:00 //+ your standard gmt time
```

For further inquire, see this [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/date_setdate.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
//set date to now:
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);

//just checking
var month = d.getMonth();
console.log(month);

//add a month
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);

//now the month is one ahead:
console.log(d.getMonth());
console.log(d);
```